# Trigger error in a database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database

First I created the audit table. Table's code is below:

```
CREATE TABLE AUDIT_NEW_1 
(   AUDIT_NUMBER NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL, 
"CUSTOMER_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULl,  
"CONCERT_ID" NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL, 
"EVENT_DATE" DATE NOT NULL,
"VENUE_ID" NUMBER(5,0), 
CONSTRAINT AUDIT_NEW_1 PRIMARY KEY (AUDIT_NUMBER)
);
```

The code for the `bookings` table

```
   CREATE TABLE Bookings
  (
    Event_Event_ID       NUMBER (5) NOT NULL ,
    Customer_Customer_ID NUMBER (5) NOT NULL ,
    Arrival_time         TIMESTAMP ,
    Evaluation           NUMBER (1) ,
    Vehicle_Number       VARCHAR2 (7)
  ) ;
```

Trigger code creation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TRIGGER LOW_EVALUAT_1
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF EVALUATION ON BOOKINGS
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
CUSTOMER_NAME  VARCHAR(20 CHAR);
CONCERT_ID     NUMBER (5,0);
EVENT_DATE      DATE;
VENUE_ID       NUMBER(5,0  );
BEGIN
IF (:NEW.EVALUATION = 0) THEN 
SELECT CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID, CONCERT.CONCERT_ID, EVENT.EVENT_DATE, VENUE.VENUE_ID
INTO CUSTOMER_NAME,CONCERT_ID,EVENT_DATE,VENUE_ID
FROM CUSTOMER, CONCERT, EVENT, VENUE
WHERE
  CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = :NEW.CUSTOMER_ID AND
  EVENT.EVENT_ID = :NEW.EVENT_ID AND
  CONCERT.CONCERT_ID = EVENT.CONCERT_ID;

INSERT INTO AUDIT_NEW_1 VALUES (AUDIT_NUMBER.NEXTVAL, CUSTOMER_NAME, CONCERT_ID,
EVENT_DATE, VENUE_ID, :NEW.EVALUATION);             
END IF;
END;
```

SQL developer returns error on those lines could you please help me how to fix the error?:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID, CONCERT.CONCERT_ID, EVENT.EVENT_DATE, VENUE.VENUE_ID
INTO CUSTOMER_NAME,CONCERT_ID,EVENT_DATE,VENUE_ID
```

Error return

```
Error(12,30): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.CUSTOMER_ID'
Error(13,24): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.EVENT_ID'
```

---

```
    CREATE TABLE Bookings
  (
    Event_Event_ID       NUMBER (5) NOT NULL ,
    Customer_Customer_ID NUMBER (5) NOT NULL ,
    Arrival_time         TIMESTAMP ,
    Evaluation           NUMBER (1) ,
    Vehicle_Number       VARCHAR2 (7)
  ) ;
ALTER TABLE Bookings ADD CHECK
(
  Evaluation IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
)
;
ALTER TABLE Bookings ADD CONSTRAINT Relation_2__IDX PRIMARY KEY
(
  Event_Event_ID, Customer_Customer_ID
)
;

CREATE TABLE Concert
  (
    Concert_ID NUMBER (5) NOT NULL ,
    Name       VARCHAR2 (25) NOT NULL ,
    Duration   NUMBER (1) NOT NULL ,
    Type       VARCHAR2 (9) NOT NULL ,
    Cost       NUMBER (25) NOT NULL
  ) ;
ALTER TABLE Concert ADD CHECK
(
  Duration IN (2, 3, 4, 5)
)
;
ALTER TABLE Concert ADD CHECK
(
  Cost BETWEEN 30 AND 500
)
;
ALTER TABLE Concert ADD CONSTRAINT Concert_PK PRIMARY KEY
(
  Concert_ID
)
;

CREATE TABLE Customer
  (
    Customer_ID      NUMBER (5) NOT NULL ,
    Full_Name        VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL ,
    Gender           VARCHAR2 (6) NOT NULL ,
    Telephone_Number NUMBER (11) NOT NULL ,
    Address          VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL
  ) ;
ALTER TABLE Customer ADD CHECK
(
  Gender IN ('F', 'M')
)
;
ALTER TABLE Customer ADD CONSTRAINT Customer_PK PRIMARY KEY
(
  Customer_ID
)
;

CREATE TABLE Event
  (
    Event_ID   NUMBER (5) NOT NULL ,
    "Date"     DATE NOT NULL ,
    Concert_ID NUMBER (5) NOT NULL ,
    Venue_ID   NUMBER (5) NOT NULL
  ) ;
ALTER TABLE Event ADD CONSTRAINT Event_PK PRIMARY KEY
(
  Event_ID
)
;

CREATE TABLE Venue
  (
    Venue_ID NUMBER (5) NOT NULL ,
    Name     VARCHAR2 (25) NOT NULL ,
    Capacity NUMBER (6) NOT NULL ,
    PostCode VARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL ,
    Location VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL
  ) ;
ALTER TABLE Venue ADD CHECK
(
  Capacity BETWEEN 1000 AND 60000
)
;
ALTER TABLE Venue ADD CONSTRAINT Venue_PK PRIMARY KEY
(
  Venue_ID
)
;

ALTER TABLE Event ADD CONSTRAINT Event_Concert_FK FOREIGN KEY ( Concert_ID ) REFERENCES Concert ( Concert_ID ) ;

ALTER TABLE Event ADD CONSTRAINT Event_Venue_FK FOREIGN KEY ( Venue_ID ) REFERENCES Venue ( Venue_ID ) ;

ALTER TABLE Bookings ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ASS_22 FOREIGN KEY ( Event_Event_ID ) REFERENCES Event ( Event_ID ) ;

ALTER TABLE Bookings ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ASS_23 FOREIGN KEY ( Customer_Customer_ID ) REFERENCES Customer ( Customer_ID ) ;
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error(12,30): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.CUSTOMER_ID'
Error(13,24): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.EVENT_ID'

Comment: OK, so does your `bookings` table have columns called `customer_id` and `event_id`? Please add the table creation statements for all of those tables to the question so we can see what you're working with. (Your `select` also looks like it needs some join conditions, but has other problems too)

Comment: i dont have 10 repuptation ta add other code

Answer (score 2):

The column names you're using inside the trigger don't match the other tables. `bookings` has columns called `customer_customer_id` and `event_event_id`, not just `customer_id` and `event_id`. Those are the immediate PLS-00049 errors.

Then `event` has `"Date"` for some reason, not `event_date`.

And you're inserting six values into the audit table when there are only five columns - there is nowhere for `:new.evaluation` to go...

These are all fairly fundamental errors.

This will compile, at least, assuming you have a sequence called `audit_num`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TRIGGER LOW_EVALUAT_1
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF EVALUATION ON BOOKINGS
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
CUSTOMER_NAME  VARCHAR(20 CHAR);
CONCERT_ID     NUMBER (5,0);
EVENT_DATE      DATE;
VENUE_ID       NUMBER(5,0  );
BEGIN
IF (:NEW.EVALUATION = 0) THEN 
SELECT CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID, CONCERT.CONCERT_ID, EVENT."Date", VENUE.VENUE_ID
INTO CUSTOMER_NAME,CONCERT_ID,EVENT_DATE,VENUE_ID
FROM CUSTOMER, CONCERT, EVENT, VENUE
WHERE
  CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = :NEW.CUSTOMER_CUSTOMER_ID AND
  EVENT.EVENT_ID = :NEW.EVENT_EVENT_ID AND
  CONCERT.CONCERT_ID = EVENT.CONCERT_ID;

INSERT INTO AUDIT_NEW_1 VALUES (AUDIT_NUMBER.NEXTVAL, CUSTOMER_NAME, CONCERT_ID,
EVENT_DATE, VENUE_ID);
END IF;
END;
/
```

But I don't think it's going to work quite as you expect; you need joins in your `select` for a start or you'll get `too_many_rows`, and you could still get that or `no_data_found`, depending on your data. It also looks like you want to `SELECT CUSTOMER.FULL_NAME, ...` rather than `SELECT CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID, ...`, based on how you've defined the local variable - so that's assuming you do want to store the name rather than the ID in the audit table, which is a bit odd in itself. You don't really need the variables, you can select as part of the insert, but that's another topic.

Answer (score 0):

your DDL:

```
 CREATE TABLE Bookings
  (
    Event_Event_ID
```

but inside trigger you have:

`EVENT.EVENT_ID = :NEW.EVENT_ID AND`
that should be:
`EVENT.EVENT_ID = :NEW.EVENT_EVENT_ID AND`